# Weird Fat Arrow '=>' usage in ASP.NET Core webapp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was going through a tutorial on ASP.NET Core 2.0 and made a fresh web app by using the following command: `dotnet new web -o mywebapp`. It created a directory containing a `Startup.cs` file containing the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace mywebapp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

I am having difficulty in understanding the syntax of the following lines:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
```

Although I am aware of lambda expressions in C#, but I have never seen this kind of usage of them. Can anybody explain what those lines mean?
Thanks!

Comment: "Weird fat arrow" guess i'am calling it this way from now on.

Comment: Just so OP is clear, it's not a single character, it's a `=` followed by a `>`!

Comment: I've heard it referred to as "fish", "lambda operator", "goes to", and now "fat arrow".  I think I like "fat arrow" best too.  Is there an official name for this "operator"?

Comment: @BradleyUffner in C# it can be named the lambda operator, and when used in expression bodied members I think that the convention is to call it the fat arrow. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator.